# Prove a lower bound $\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty k(t) g(t) e^{i\theta t}dt\right|\geq C \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|dt$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Let $k(t)$ be any function absolutely integrable over $(-\infty,\infty)$ and let
$$g(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(u) e^{itu}du$$
Consider
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty k(t) g(t) e^{i\theta t}dt$$
can we find a constant $C$ such that
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty k(t) g(t) e^{i\theta t}dt\right|\geq C \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|dt$$
?

Comment: $C=0$ works. Seriously, what properties is $C$ expected to have (besides being positive); can it depend on $k$, for example? What if $k\equiv 0$? Anyway, there is no hope for such an estimate even for a fixed $k$  –  you have no way to prevent cancellation inside the absolute value on the left.